# How to model a 2D world in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm making a game. The game consists of an infinite plane. Units must be on a discrete square, so they can be located with a simple `Location { x :: Int, y :: Int }`

There might be many kinds of `Unit`s. Some might be creatures, and some are just objects, like a block of stone, or wood (think 2d minecraft there). Many will be empty (just grass or whatever).

How would you model this in Haskell? I've considered doing the below, but what about Object vs Creature? they might have different fields? Normalize them all on Unit?

```
data Unit = Unit { x :: Int, y :: Int, type :: String, ... many shared properties... }
```

I've also considered having a location type

```
data Location = Location { x :: Int, y :: Int, unit :: Unit } 
-- or this
data Location = Location { x :: Int, y :: Int }
data Unit = Unit { unitFields... , location :: Location }
```

Do you have any ideas? In an OO language, I probably would have had `Location` or `Unit` inherit from the other, and made the specific types of Unit inherit from each other.

Another consideration is this will be sending lots of these objects over the wire, so I'll need to serialize them to JSON for use on the client, and don't want to write tons of parsing boilerplate.

Comment: Use a `Data.Map.Map` as your grid.

Comment: So have the x an y be no more than a key in the Map, and Units just have their various fields? What about when it comes time to send them down to the client, should I send down a map/hash there too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Location` is just a simple two-dimensional `Point` type.

I would advise against tying `Unit`s to the location they're in; just use a `Map Location Unit` to handle the map between positions on the grid and what (if anything) is present there.

As far as the specific types of `Unit` go, I would, at the very least, recommend factoring common fields out into a data type:

```
data UnitInfo = UnitInfo { ... }

data BlockType = Grass | Wood | ...

data Unit
  = NPC UnitInfo AgentID
  | Player UnitInfo PlayerID
  | Block UnitInfo BlockType
```

or similar.

Generally, factor common things out into their own data-type, and keep data as simple and "isolated" as possible (i.e. move things like "what location is this unit at?" into separate structures *associating* the two, so that individual data-types are as "timeless", reusable and abstract as possible).

Having a `String` for the "type" of a `Unit` is a strong antipattern in Haskell; it generally indicates you're trying to implement dynamic typing or OOP structures with data types, which is a bad fit.

Your JSON requirement complicates things, but [this FAQ entry](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FAQ#I.27m_making_an_RPG._Should_I_define_a_type_for_each_kind_of_monster.2C_and_a_type_class_for_them.3F) shows a good example of how to idiomatically achieve this kind of genericity in Haskell with no `String` typing or fancy type-class hacks, using functions and data-types as the primary units of abstraction. Of course, the former causes you problems here; it's hard to serialise functions as JSON. However, you could maintain a map from an ADT representing a "type" of creature or block, etc., and its actual implementation:

```
-- records containing functions to describe arbitrary behaviour; see FAQ entry
data BlockOps = BlockOps { ... }
data CreatureOps = CreatureOps { ... }
data Block = Block { ... }
data Creature = Creature { ... }
data Unit = BlockUnit Block | CreatureUnit Creature
newtype GameField = GameField (Map Point Unit)

-- these types are sent over the network, and mapped *back* to the "rich" but
-- non-transferable structures describing their behaviour; of course, this means
-- that BlockOps and CreatureOps must contain a BlockType/CreatureType to map
-- them back to this representation
data BlockType = Grass | Wood | ...
data CreatureType = ...
blockTypes :: Map BlockType BlockOps
creatureTypes :: Map CreatureType CreatureOps
```

This lets you have all the extensibility and don't-repeat-yourself nature of typical OOP structures, while keeping the functional simplicity and allowing simple network transfer of game states.

Generally, you should avoid thinking in terms of inheritance and other OOP concepts; instead, try to think of dynamic behaviour in terms of functions and composition of simpler structures. A function is the most powerful tool in functional programming, hence the name, and can represent any complex pattern of behaviour. It's also best not to let requirements like network play influence your basic design; like the example above, it's almost always possible to layer these things on *top* of a design built for expressiveness and simplicity, rather than constraints like communication format.

Comment: Still digesting, but sooo helpful. Thank you!

Comment: One thing that is throwing me for a loop is an id field. I'm planning on storing state in redis, and the JSON api will require some communication in terms of ids. Should I add an id field to my Units, or associate it somehow? For example, a new client might want to say "I'm new! Give me back my player object!" They'll want their own id, but they'll be sending a few fields to specify about their player. The server generates it and returns it. So their object doesn't have one, the one I return does.

Comment: @SeanClarkHess: Yes, an `IntMap Unit` or something of the sort to associate identifiers with units is probably the best choice there; including the identifier itself in the `Unit` is reasonable too. I would consider factoring out the fields specified by the client into their own structure, and include it in `Creature`, so that "harmless" bits the client can decide are isolated from things they shouldn't be able to touch (e.g. health points); say `CreatureTemplate`.

Comment: @SeanClarkHess: Then you just need e.g. `makeCreature :: CreatureTemplate -> Creature` and `createCreatureUnit :: Creature -> M Unit` (for some monad `M`).